# Get JSON element value from another value in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am new in Json,and I need to fetch the value of one element from another value. Consider I have created an Json Array using code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("email", "E"+i);
    obj.put("fname", "F"+i);
    obj.put("lname", "L"+i);
    array.put(obj);
}
jsonObject.put("MyArray" , array);
```

Its in the form

```
{"MyArray":[{"username":"E1","fname":"F1","lname":"L1"},{"username":"E2","fname":"F2","lname":"L2"},{"username":"E3","fname":"F3","lname":"L3"} ]}
```

I need to find the value of fname and lname whose email is "`E2`" How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: You may use `JsonPath` library which syntax can navigate through JSON tree with Regex [https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

Comment: Whwere is the email E2?

Comment: @Valijon: I shall give it a try, seems interesting.

Comment: @Abdelhak : that comes on the fly at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your code add this and change the if-statement to reflect what you want to do with the object:

```
JSONArray t = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MyArray");
for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) t.get(i);
    if(temp.get("email").equals("E2")) {

        //do whatever with the object

        System.out.println(temp.get("fname"));
        System.out.println(temp.get("lname"));

        break;
    }
}
```

This code first looks up where the object with `email` E2 is located, then gets the `fname` and `lname` values from that object.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks alot.

Comment: No need for thanks, just accept the answer so others with the same question can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you may need to keep track of this information anyways, you can create a Person class and then see the Driver class which takes you JSON array and the username you want and then returns person matching that username.

Driver.class

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by fbgrecojr on 12/5/15.
 */
public class Driver {

    public static Person getKeyFromValue(String json, String username){
        Person toReturn = new Person();

        try{
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json);

            for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); ++i){
                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                if(obj.getString("username").equals(username)){
                    toReturn.set_username(obj.getString("username"));
                    toReturn.set_email(obj.getString("email"));
                    toReturn.set_first(obj.getString("first"));
                    toReturn.set_last(obj.getString("last"));
                    break;
                }
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            //do something
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Person.class

```
/**
 * Created by fbgrecojr on 12/5/15.
 */
public class Person {

    private String _username, _first, _last, _email;

    public Person(){

    }

    public String get_email() {
        return _email;
    }

    public void set_email(String _email) {
        this._email = _email;
    }

    public String get_first() {
        return _first;
    }

    public void set_first(String _first) {
        this._first = _first;
    }

    public String get_last() {
        return _last;
    }

    public void set_last(String _last) {
        this._last = _last;
    }

    public String get_username() {
        return _username;
    }

    public void set_username(String _username) {
        this._username = _username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank , I wanted to keep it simple though as I need it for my android project which is large enough.